# some question of closed subscheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $Y$ be a closed subscheme of a scheme $X$ and let be the inclsion morphism $i:Y \rightarrow X$.

Then morphism $i$ is quasi-compact?

If it is true, why quasi-compact?

Comment: Do you know when an open immersion is of finite type?

Comment: Sorry, Matt. $Y$ is a closed subscheme.

Comment: Ah, then since it is of finite type it is quasi-compact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true. Take an open affine $U$ of $X$. The preimage $i^{-1}(U)$ is a closed subscheme of $U$, so is affine itself, in particular quasi-compact.